# Flaky errors when fetching & rendering data using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I'm fetching data from an API & rendering the results. This is working for a while & then I'm getting the following error: `itemList.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function` & also `Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.`

Any ideas on why is this happening?

This is my code sample:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ItemList = () => {
    const [items, setItem] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "<redacted-api-endpoint>";

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();

                return setItem(json.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error", error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {
                items.map((item, index) => {
                    const { name, title, description, image, price } = item;

                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <img src={image} alt="item" width="100" height="auto" />
                            <p>{name}</p>
                            <p>{title}</p>
                            <p>{description}</p>
                            <p>{price}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect(callback, dependencies)` is for side-effects hook that runs after the component is mounted, it manages the side-effects in functional components. callback argument is a function to put the side-effect logic. dependencies is a list of dependencies of your side-effect: being props or state values. `useEffect(callback, dependencies)` invokes the callback after ***initial mounting***, and on later renderings, if any value inside dependencies has changed.

In your first/initial render, the component is mounted with it's initial state which is `const [items, setItem] = useState("");` and you are maping over an empty string.

> Solution:

consider adding short circuiting, or add item in your initial state to prevent the error.

```
    <>
            {
                items && items.map((item, index) => {
                    const { name, title, description, image, price } = item;

                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <img src={image} alt="item" width="100" height="auto" />
                            <p>{name}</p>
                            <p>{title}</p>
                            <p>{description}</p>
                            <p>{price}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
```

take a quick look at official react docs concerning [useEffect](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook