# Getting error after fetching data in useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

**Home.jsx**

````
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=11&lon=11&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=metric&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  });

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <DataContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
        <section className="main-section">
          <Navbar />
          <Toprow />
        </section>

        <section className="side-section">
          <Aside />
        </section>
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}; ```


** top row component where i am using the data**
````

const { data } = useContext(DataContext);

and then consolelogging it giving this error

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Toprow.jsx:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')
at Toprow (Toprow.jsx:52:1)

```
check website at weatherflu-react.netlify.app
and i check this flow which i think says this thing better but i dont know what to do
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72033780/flaky-errors-when-fetching-rendering-data-using-react-hooks
```

Comment: As you can see, the error is located in Toprow.jsx. But without seeing the file, it will be really difficult if not impossible to help you further.

Comment: Where are you accessing the temp property? Make sure that the object the property belongs to isn't undefined or something like that.

Comment: You might have an infinite loop in your useEffect.      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [] ); // Run this code only once. Your are fetching data, setting the state, and it rerenders and fetches data again, doing an infinite loop. dependancy array [] will run it only once